# java shortcuts to Pojos?

Tags: java, oop, styles

I am wondering a stupid question but well, I love to learn :)

Say I got the following code :

```
public String method(<T> a)
{
String dataA = a.getB().getC().getD();
}
```

At what point it becomes interesting to define a map which cache our requests and holds this :

```
Map<<T>, String> m;
m.put(a, dataA);
```

and then of course, 
[SNIP the usual tests of nullity and adding the object if it is missing and so forth plus the refreshing issues]
    return m.get(a);

Let me stress that the successive gets are NOT costy (no things such as DB calls, or JNDI lookups).

It's just that it's clearer if we define a dictionnary rather than read the whole string of "gets".

I consider that making a get call is NEARLY "free" in CPU time. Again, I suppose that retrieving the data from an hashmap is NOT exactly free but nearly (at least, in my case, it is :) ).

My question is really in terms of readibility, not performance.

Thanks !

Comment: re: `a.getB().getC().getD()`...see [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the article about the Law of Demeter, that was definitively interesting !

Answer (score 4):

To increase readability (and [decrease dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)), you should define an accessor in A, such as

```
public String getDataA() {
  return getB().getC().getD();
}
```

Then your calling code becomes

```
String dataA = a.getDataA();
```

You may say that you would need too many such shortcut methods in A, cluttering its interface. That is actually a sign of a class design issue. Either A has grown too big and complex (in which case it may be better to partition it into more than one class), or the code needing all these far away pieces of data actually belongs to somewhere else - say into B or C - rather than to A's client.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to consider:

Apache Beanutils has a lot of utilities for this sort of thing: http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/

java.util.properties, if the values are all strings

If you really want to access things like this you can also look at using groovy instead. All lookups on maps in groovy can be done with '.' notation and it also supports a "safe" accessor which will check for nulls.

Answer (score 0):

MVEL is another option:

```
String d = (String) MVEL.eval("b.?c.?d", a);
```

I will say that data dictionaries lead to typesafety issues.  There's no guarantee that everyone puts the right types in the right data elements, or even defines all the required elements.

Also, when using an expression language as above, there's also typesafety issues, as there's no compile time check on the actual expression to make sure that a) it makes sense, and b) it returns the right type.